# Counting category items for each date in dataset (C# with linq)

Tags: c#, linq

I am new to C# and linq and are trying to create a new dataset based on the old one. I have made a dummy dataset, however the real dataset contains a lot more fields which are not relevant to this case.

This is the similar the dataset with a few items to showcase what i want to accomplish:

```
entries : [
     {
       timestamp: "2021-06-01",
       category: "banana"
     },
     {
       timestamp: "2021-06-01",
       category: "apple"
     },
     {
       timestamp: "2021-08-14",
       category: "apple"
     },
    ]
```

This is how i want it:

```
entries : [
     {
       timestamp: "2021-06-01",
       fruitCount: [
          { category: "banana", count: 1 },
          { category: "apple", count: 1 }
       ]
     },
     {
       timestamp: "2021-08-14",
       fruitCount: [
          { category: "apple", count: 1 }
       ]
     }
    ]
```

How do i create a GroupBy statement which gets me to the desired list?
As I said, I am very new to this and would appreciate some help in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use `GroupBy` twice as you want to group by timestamp and within those timestamps again for the fruits. Here's an example:

```cs
//test data
var entries = new[] { new
{
    timestamp = "2021-06-01",
    category = "banana"
},
    new {
        timestamp = "2021-06-01",
        category = "apple"
    },
    new {
        timestamp = "2021-08-14",
        category = "apple"
    }
};

var result = entries
    //first we group by timestamps
    .GroupBy(x => x.timestamp) 
    //transform the data to the new format
    .Select(x => new
    {
        //the timestamp is the key we grouped by
        timestamp = x.Key,
        //build up the fruitCount object
        fruitCount = x
            //create subgroups for the fruits
            .GroupBy(y => y.category)
            //transform the fruit groups to the new format
            .Select(y => new
            {
                category = y.Key,
                //count together all fruits within the subgroup
                count = y.Count(),
            })
            .ToList(),
    })
    .ToList();
```